# Guessing the correlation structure of a mixed model

Tags: r, linear-model, covariance

If you would fit a small sample like with the standard framework for linear models. Would you suggest from the residuals any special correlation structure like compound symmetry or first order autoregression?

```
Y<-data.frame(response=c(10,19,27,28,9,13,25,29,4,10,20,18,5,6,12,17),
               treatment=factor(rep(1:4,4)),
               subject=factor(rep(1:4,each=4))
               )
fit<-lm(response~-1+treatment,Y)
```

Comment: Have you really got just 4 people, each with 4 treatments?

Comment: Yes, I also think it is not meaning full to get some informations from a smll sample. I got this data from ANOVA Repeated Measures (Ellen R. Girden, 1992)

Answer (score 3):

First order AR (or any order AR) seems to me to be more appropriate for longitudinal data, which yours doesn't seem to be (from the code) unless there is some reason to suspect that factor 1 should be closer to factor 2 than to factor 3 (and so on). This might be if they are (say) different doses of a medicine.

I usually test several covariance structures and use information criteria to decide on which to use (in my experience the different criteria usually agree; but people have strong opinions on which is best). I would test at least compound symmetry and unstructured.

Comment: I tried to say: how to get any information about the correlation structure of this data in the context of a mixed model. For "unstructured" I get no values `lme(response~-1+treatment,Y,random=~1|subject,correlation=corSymm())`

Comment: you could fit the model with compound symmetry (`corCompSymm` or, approximately, just leaving out the `correlation` statement entirely) and then look at the realized correlations (which will be *very* noisy).

Comment: Are you sure AIC (or other information criteria) can be trusted with the kind of sample size present in the OP's example?

Comment: @macro Well, no; but nothing really can be trusted with that sample size. At least, nothing that I know of.

Comment: Of course but in this case (especially with the unstructured covariance, which eats up 10 of the 16 degrees of freedom) you're very far from the "asymptopia" required for the usual AIC (or similar information criteria) to be meaningful. I don't have a great suggestion. Maybe AICc (which I'm not familiar with - I've just heard it's the "finite sample" AIC) would be viable.

Comment: $AICc = AIC + \frac{2k(k + 1)}{n - k - 1}$ where k is number of paramters. So, when n is small, AICc will impose a very stiff penalty on each parameter added to the model.

Answer (score 2):

```
## data
Y<-data.frame(response=c(10,19,27,28,9,13,25,29,4,10,20,18,5,6,12,17),
               treatment=factor(rep(1:4,4)),
               subject=factor(rep(1:4,each=4))
               )

library(nlme)
```

Use `gls` to make the results AIC-comparable with `lme()`:

```
fit <- gls(response~-1+treatment,Y)
## unstructured (fails)
fit2 <- try(lme(response~-1+treatment,Y,random=~1|subject,
                correlation=corSymm()))
## random effect but no correlation structure
## equiv. corCompSymm with positive rho?
fit3 <- lme(response~-1+treatment,Y,random=~1|subject)
fit4 <- lme(response~-1+treatment,Y,random=~1|subject,
            correlation=corCompSymm()) ## parameter est -> rho=0 ??
fit5 <- lme(response~-1+treatment,Y,random=~1|subject,
            correlation=corAR1())

options(digits=3)
AIC(fit,fit3,fit4,fit5) 
##   df  AIC
## fit   5 90.8
## fit3  6 82.2
## fit4  7 84.2
## fit5  7 82.7
```

The plain grouping model is best (compound symmetry adds a parameter
but doesn't improve the fit at all), all but the plain lm model are
nearly equivalent.

Compute empirical correlation of residuals:

```
empCor <- function(mod) {
    rr <- residuals(mod)
    ## reshape
    rmat <- matrix(rr,ncol=4,dimnames=list(treatment=1:4,subject=1:4))
    ## set residuals to zero mean for each treatment
    ## (already true in this case)
    rmat <- sweep(rmat,1,rowMeans(rmat),"-")
    covmat <- tcrossprod(rmat)/3  ## sample covariate matrix
    ## (denominator might be wrong since we are already looking
    ##  at model residuals, but it doesn't affect the correlation
    ##  calculation)
    cov2cor(covmat)
}
```

Theoretical (computed) correlation:

```
thCor <- function(mod) {
    corMatrix(mod$modelStruct$corStruct)[[1]]
}
options(digits=2)
```

Ignoring grouping structure, there is strong positive
within-group correlation in the residuals:

```
empCor(fit)
##          treatment
## treatment    1    2    3    4
##         1 1.00 0.85 0.80 0.96
##         2 0.85 1.00 0.93 0.83
##         3 0.80 0.93 1.00 0.88
##         4 0.96 0.83 0.88 1.00
```

Once we account for the grouping structure, the within-group
correlation is noisier:

```
empCor(fit3)
##          treatment
## treatment     1     2      3      4
##         1  1.00 -0.33 -0.937 -0.271
##         2 -0.33  1.00  0.263 -0.596
##         3 -0.94  0.26  1.000  0.073
##         4 -0.27 -0.60  0.073  1.000
```

I don't quite understand why these are different, but there's
a lot of nonlinear fitting going on here, so a lot of opportunity
for getting stuck and/or non-intuitive outcomes

```
empCor(fit5)
##          treatment
## treatment      1    2      3    4
##         1  1.000 0.22 -0.072 0.48
##         2  0.220 1.00  0.826 0.55
##         3 -0.072 0.83  1.000 0.73
##         4  0.481 0.55  0.733 1.00
```

Theoretical correlation of AR1 (AR1 parameter=0.73):

```
thCor(fit5)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,] 1.00 0.73 0.53 0.38
## [2,] 0.73 1.00 0.73 0.53
## [3,] 0.53 0.73 1.00 0.73
## [4,] 0.38 0.53 0.73 1.00
```

I would take this all with a great big grain of salt.